# Put message in dead letter queue in azure service bus from node js client

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an azure function and in the call back function it receives a message from the topic, some times when the function is not able to process the message then from this node js code I would like to put that message in the dead letter queue which may be processed manually later, I tried going through the documentation and I only found examples to read a message from the dead letter and put it to the dead letter while receiving it from service bus object, In my case its a callback method so I don't need to create a service bus object, is there a way by which in the call back function I will be able to put a message in the dead letter

I am using

"@azure/service-bus": "7.0.3"

I was following this documentation

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/

my function.json is :

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "sbMessage",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "dummy-topic-name",
      "subscriptionName": "dummy_subscription",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsServiceBus"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this readme doc it has an example for reading from the dead letter:

```
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/typescript/src/advanced/movingMessagesToDLQ.ts
```

I am getting message in this callback :

sample code:

```
module.exports = async function (context, sbMessage) {
    context.log('ServiceBus  message', sbMessage);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

throwing an exception from the node js function puts the message in dead letter queue

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to send information to the dead letter directly without establishing a client based on the service bus (at least as far as NodeJs is concerned). Please check the trigger based on NodeJS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=javascript#usage

You will find that there is no corresponding usage at all(If you based on C#, it is possiable.).

You can try try to create service bus client and use `deadLetterMessage`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusreceiver?view=azure-node-latest#deadLetterMessage_ServiceBusReceivedMessage__DeadLetterOptions____key__string___any_

Answer (score 0):

I was working on Azure Bus Service as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusreceiver?view=azure-node-latest#deadLetterMessage_ServiceBusReceivedMessage__DeadLetterOptions____key__string___any_

The reference on how to pass a message to DLQ can be found on above link.

Basically you need to call `deadLetterMessage` method on the `Receiver` you've created.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/da8d311b88dff7e93fd1835f0bf034055a8a0b2a/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/javascript/advanced/movingMessagesToDLQ.js#L61-L64

```
    const connectionString = process.env.SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING || "<connection string>";
    const queueName = process.env.QUEUE_NAME || "<queue name>";
    const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

    const receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(queueName);

    await receiver.deadLetterMessage(messages[0], {
      deadLetterReason: "Incorrect Recipe type",
      deadLetterErrorDescription: "Recipe type does not match preferences."
    });
```

On top of this, you can disable the `autoCompleteMessages` for full control of how you want to complete or discard or move message to DLQ.

Comment: Where you can se autoCompleteMessages using ServiceBusClient?

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, it is **not** possible interactively send a message in dead-letter.

I found out that [autocomplete=false is only supported for C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python#configuration).

This basically means that **the only way to dead letter a message is throw an exception**.

Answer (score 0):

When defining your Queue you want to check "Enable dead lettering on message expiration" and set the "Max delivery count" for the number of retries you want.
Then, if your function throws an exception, it will retry 'n times and then move it to the dead letter queue.